# Prove that $SL_2(F_4)$ is isomorphic to $A_5$ by giving explicit isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

Prove that $SL_2(F_4)$ is isomorphic to $A_5$ by giving explicit isomorphism.

I'm really getting no idea to do this one (except I just noticed $|SL_2(F_4)|=60$ and we may relate $\mathbb{sign}$ of a permutation with determinant)

Comment: Note that SL_2(F_4) acts on the projective line on F_4, which has 5 points. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line

Comment: Got it, thanks you ! nice observation by the way !